# Xerces XML validation with XSD

Tags: c++, xerces

I try to validate XML file using a given XSD grammar file. But for now it always return error saying `no  declaration found for element ...` and that for each element or attribute I have in my XML file.

To create the XSD i used that [Free online XSD generator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) and if I check my xml within that XSD using the (Validator)[http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html] on the same site, everything looks fine.

So why Xerces fails ?

I use the following code to validate:

```
      XercesDOMParser domParser;
      if (domParser.loadGrammar(schemaFilePath.c_str(), Grammar::SchemaGrammarType) == NULL)
      {
        throw Except("couldn't load schema");
      }

      ParserErrorHandler parserErrorHandler;

      domParser.setErrorHandler(&parserErrorHandler);
      domParser.setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
      domParser.setDoNamespaces(true);
      domParser.setDoSchema(true);
      domParser.setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);

      domParser.parse(xmlFilePath.c_str());
      if(domParser.getErrorCount() != 0)
      {     
        throw Except("Invalid XML vs. XSD: " + parserErrorHandler.getErrors()); //merge a error coming from my interceptor ....
      }
```

My XML test file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schemes signature="9fadde05">
    <!-- NOTE: Do not modify this file. 
     Any modifications will invalidate the signature and result in an invalid file! 
     This is an example scheme, param_set etc... can be rename / market or / product
    -->
    <scheme>
        <name>test1</name>
        <other>test2</other>
    </scheme>
    <param_set>
        <input>
            <height min="1060" max="1100" />
            <width min="1900" max="1940" />
        </input>
    </param_set>
</schemes>
```

And the XSD I use is:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="schemes">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="scheme">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="other"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="param_set">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="input">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="height">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="min"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="max"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="width">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="min"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="max"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="signature"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: In short, possible workaround is using DOMLSParser as described in [link](http://codesynthesis.com/~boris/data/load-grammar/load-grammar-dom.cxx) and blog [link](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/03/15/validating-external-schemas-xerces-cxx/).
But I don't know the root cause of this problem. 
Also, I found two possible duplicate questions: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870797/xerces-c-xml-schema-validation-not-working) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455071/validating-document-in-xerces-c).

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at those link ASAP.

Comment: Re-phrase my answer: In short, one possible workaround is using DOMLSParser as described in [this sample program](http://codesynthesis.com/~boris/data/load-grammar/load-grammar-dom.cxx) which is described in [this blog](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/03/15/validating-external-schemas-xerces-cxx/).

But I don't know the root cause of this problem. 

Also, I found two possible duplicate questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870797/xerces-c-xml-schema-validation-not-working) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455071/validating-document-in-xerces-c).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solve that issue the following code, and I think the `setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation` is the trick. Note that I had also to rebuild an [`absolute` path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144256/infinite-recursion-when-i-build-an-absolute-path-using-boost/22166594#22166594) for the XSD.

```
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    {
      XercesDOMParser domParser;
      bfs::path pXSD = absolute(schemaFilePath);      
      if (domParser.loadGrammar(pXSD.string().c_str(), Grammar::SchemaGrammarType) == NULL)
      {
        throw Except("couldn't load schema");
      }

      ParserErrorHandler parserErrorHandler;

      domParser.setErrorHandler(&parserErrorHandler);
      domParser.setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
      domParser.setDoNamespaces(true);
      domParser.setDoSchema(true);
      domParser.setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);

      domParser.setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation(pXSD.string().c_str());

      domParser.parse(xmlFilePath.c_str());
      if(domParser.getErrorCount() != 0)
      {     
        throw Except("Invalid XML vs. XSD: " + parserErrorHandler.getErrors()); //merge a error coming from my interceptor ....
      }
    }
    XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just leaving some info here for others who may experience some troubles with `xercesc`.

The solution provided by the question author is useful, yet may not apply to your case.
First, if you use `setExternalSchemaLocation`, you do not need to `loadGrammar`.

Second, if your schema handles namespaces, try out `setExternalSchemaLocation` as well.

My code:

```
xmlParser = std::make_unique<xercesc::XercesDOMParser>();
std::string xsdPath = "http://your.namespace.com path/to/schema.xsd";

xmlParser->setValidationScheme(xercesc::XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
xmlParser->setDoNamespaces(true);
xmlParser->setDoSchema(true);
xmlParser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);

//Finally...
xmlParser->setExternalSchemaLocation(xsdPath.c_str());
```

Note that there is no call to loadGrammar. Also, note that `xercesc` will not attempt to parse the schema until you call

```
xmlParser->parse(...);
```