# Error handling in validating xerces-c SAX parser

Tags: xml, validation, xerces-c

I am trying to use Xerces-C to parse XML with a validating XSD or DTD.  Unfortunately, validation errors are not reported.  Here's how I am setting it up:

```
saxParser = new MySAXParser;
saxParser->setDoNamespaces(true);
saxParser->setValidationScheme(MySAXParser::Val_Auto);
saxParser->setDoSchema(true);
saxParser->setValidationConstraintFatal(true);
saxParser->setExitOnFirstFatalError(true);
MySAXErrorHandler handler;
saxParser->setErrorHandler(&handler);
saxParser->parse(...);
```

Unfortunately, this method of my error handler is never called:

```
virtual void fatalError(const XN::SAXParseException &exc) { throw exc; }
```

When a validation error occurs, an internal Xerces method *is* called:

```
void XMLValidator::emitError(const XMLValid::Codes toEmit
, const XMLCh* const text1
, const XMLCh* const text2
, const XMLCh* const text3
, const XMLCh* const text4)
```

However, it gets here:

```
if (fErrorReporter)
```

but fErrorReporter is null, so nothing is reported.  I would like to install an error reporter (it is of type XMLErrorReporter), where I could track the message and/or throw my own exception, but I don't know how to do that.

I *can* call saxParser->getErrorCount() and it returns non-zero, which is good.  That let's me report "There was an error!".  But the error text and position wasn't captured.

UPDATE: This is Xerces-c version 3.1

Note I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455071/validating-document-in-xerces-c) but it doesn't seem to work with SAX.

Comment: Perhaps it is not a fatalerror but just an error have you overridden all the error reporting methods?

Comment: Yup that was it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Derp, this was my mistake.  My error handler object was built with:

```
class MySAXErrorHandler : public HandlerBase {
public:
    virtual void fatalError(const SAXParseException &exc) { throw exc; }
};
```

While structural errors are reported via fatalError(), validation errors are reported via error().  The HandlerBase class has a default implementation of error() to "do nothing".  Overriding error() in addition to fatalError() solved the problem.